# Powershell - rename users (loop)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, rename, bulk-rename-utility

I'm trying to update a few (560) users on my domain.
they are using incomplete and/or incorrect names according to my workers DB.

I created a CSV file containing this info:

```
samaccoutname,Name,givenname,surname
r001248,ADRIANA DAS COUVE ,ADRIANA ,DAS COUVE
r020230,ALEXANDRA DAS NEVE ,ALEXANDRA ,DAS NEVE
```

This is my code but it isn't working out:

```
#
# Script.ps1
#

Import-Module activedirectory

$userlist = Import-Csv C:\Users\r013462\Documents\Atualização_AD.csv -Delimiter ","

foreach ($user in $userlist)
{
    $GivenN = $user.givenName
    $FullN = $user.Name
    $SurN = $user.surName
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname | Set-ADUser -GivenName $GivenN -Surname $SurN -DisplayName $FullN
}
```

suggestions?

Comment: Your subexpression `$()` is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: changed ; to , 
and these changes, still not working
foreach ($user in $userlist)
{
 $GivenN = $user.givenName
 $FullN = $user.Name
 $SurN = $user.surName
 Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname | Set-ADUser -GivenName $GivenN -Surname $SurN -DisplayName $FullN
}

Comment: added -delimiter "," 
not worked

Comment: getting this as return:
 Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
[ERROR] At C:\Users\r013462\source\repos\rename-project\rename-project\Script.ps1:14 char:23
[ERROR] +     Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samaccountname | Set-ADUser -GivenName ...

Comment: Missing character capitalized. `samaccoutname,Name,givenname,surname` -> `samaccouNtname,Name,givenname,surname`

Comment: @BenH compiled but haven't changed anything in Active Directory. continuing investigating.
thanks for now

Comment: actually it changed display name but didn't changed name parameter on AD. Continuing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally, came to a solution!

if you want to do it, you have to use same parameters of my csv orginally posted and use this script:

```
#
# Script.ps1
#

Import-Module activedirectory

$varCSV = ""
$userlist = Import-Csv -Path $varCSV -Delimiter ","

foreach ($user in $userlist)
{
    $samN = $user.samaccouNtname
    $GivenN = $user.GivenName
    $FullN = $user.Name
    $SurN = $user.Surname
    $dn = (Get-ADUser -Identity $samN).DistinguishedName
    Get-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName | Set-ADUser -GivenName $GivenN -SurName $SurN -DisplayName $FullN  
    Try {
        Rename-ADObject $dn -NewName $FullN
    }

    catch {
        Write-Output "usuario repetido: " ($user.samaccountname) | Out-File C:\errors.txt -Append
    }

}
```